# ajax loader does not append sometime

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, ajax

I am building web app using .net and i am using ajax to get some data from the server.
I want to make custom ajax loader for each function, like: if its to delete somthing i want to call the function X() if its to keep alive the session i dont want load at all and if its to get data of a user i want the function Y().
I know that if i call to `$(document).ajaxStart(` so every time from now when ajax call is starting so the same function will run.
because i want different function this what i tried:

```
function X() {
    var flag = true;
    $(document).ajaxStart(function () {
        if (flag) {
            $('#loadDiv').show();
        }
    });
    $(document).ajaxStop(function () {
        if (flag) {
            $('#loadDiv').hide();
            flag = false;
        }
    });
```

and i did another one for the Y() function, and then before the ajax call i am calling to X or Y.
the problem is that sometimes the loading functions are not working, only if i am clicking few more times its firing, but even if its not working the ajax calling is running on the background.
there is a better way to make custom ajax loaderr to other actions? what i did wrong?

Comment: No idea what JS library you're using and your code is incomplete, but you may want to look at JSONP so that you can have one AJAX routine and based on the server result, call the desired function.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a [facade](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Facade_pattern) for jQuery `ajax` function where you'll handle the progress:

```
ajax = (function ($) {
  function showProgress() { $('#loadDiv').show(); }
  function hideProgress() { $('#loadDiv').hide(); }

  function ajax(url, parameters) {
    // We don't want to mutate the state of "parameters".
    var copy = $.extend(parameters, {});

    if (copy.progress) {
      // Showing the progress.
      showProgress();

      // On completion (success or error) hiding the progress.
      if (copy.complete) {
        copy.complete = function() { 
          hideProgress(); 
          copy.complete.apply(this, arguments); 
        };
      } else {
        copy.complete = hideProgress;
      }
    }

    return $.ajax(url, copy);
  }

  return ajax;
})(jQuery);
```

You can call your new `ajax` function the same same you'd call the `jQuery.ajax` but now you can specify one additional parameter called `progress` which indicates whether to display a progress indicator:

```
ajax('/my/url', { 
  type: 'get',
  success: function() { ... },
  progress: true
});
```

As an alternative (in case you don't like the presence of a custom `ajax` function) you could make a proxy for `jQuery.ajax`:

```
(function ($) {
  function showProgress() { $('#loadDiv').show(); }
  function hideProgress() { $('#loadDiv').hide(); }

  var ajaxOriginal = $.ajax;

  $.ajax = function(url, parameters) {
    // Same as above but you need to call "ajaxOriginal" 
    // internally instead of "$.ajax".
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Personally, I'd prefer the first approach as it's a bit more transparent.

Hope this helps.